# The dual of elements $E$, $F$, and $H$ of $U_h(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ corresponds to which element of $F_h(\mathrm{SL}_2)$ by isomorphism?

Tags: lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

$\newcommand{\sl}{\mathfrak{sl}}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $U_h(\sl_2)$ be the quantized universal enveloping algebra of $\sl_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $F_h(\SL_2)$ be the quantized function algebra of $\SL(2, \mathbb{C})$. Theorem 7.1.4 in the book [“A Guide to Quantum Groups” by V. Chari and A. N. Pressley](https://www.cambridge.org/jp/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/guide-quantum-groups?format=PB&isbn=9780521558846) shows that the finite dual of $U_h(\sl_2)$ is isomorphic to $F_h(\SL_2)$.

**Question**
The dual of elements $E$, $F$, and $H$ of $U_h(\sl_2)$ corresponds to which element of $F_h(\SL_2)$ by isomorphism?